# Can't save django object to mysql (ManyToManyField)

Tags: django

```
class MyArticle(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=765)
    clicks = models.ManyToManyField(MyArticle, through='ClickEvent')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class ClickEvent(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(MyArticle)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()



art = MyArticle.objects.create(id = article_id)
eusr = UserProfile.objects.create(username = username)
cl = ClickEvent(article = art, user = eusr, timestamp = datetime.now())
cl.save()
```

These objects are all created, but when I try to save the click it fails, and I can't figure why?

cl.save() # fails

I followed the steps described here, but can't seem to see what's missing.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: I resolved the issue. 
I was getting the following error:
(1054, "Unknown column 'article' in 'field list'")

The problem was that syncdb does not update the created tables, so they need to be dropped first, and created again. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293300/unknown-column-user-id-error-in-django-view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the art and eusr items first -- ie:

```
art.save()
eusr.save()
```

Before calling cl.save()

Comment: `create` does that automatically, so that isn't the problem.